# Como puedo hacerle un formateo de texto a un chat?

Tags: c#

estoy desarrollando un programa de comunicacion que tiene un chat y quiero que el chat respete el cuerpo del texto con viñetas, puntos, negrita, etc.
Cuando alguien copie y pegue texto de otro lugar.

Comment: ¿Has probado algún código? Muéstralo para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Todo depende que uses para mostrar el texto... sin mas aclaracion no hay mucha ayuda para darte

Comment: [RTF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format).